# Parsing multiline records in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Here is my RDD[String]

```
M1 module1
PIP a Z A
PIP b Z B
PIP c Y n4

M2 module2
PIP a I n4
PIP b O D
PIP c O n5
```

and so on. 
Basically, I need a RDD of key (containing the second word on line1) and values of the subsequent PIP lines that can be iterated upon.

I've tried the following

```
val usgPairRDD = usgRDD.map(x => (x.split("\\n")(0), x))
```

but this gives me the following output

```
(,)
(M1 module1,M1 module1)
(PIP a Z A,PIP a Z A)
(PIP b Z B,PIP b Z B)
(PIP c Y n4,PIP c Y n4)
(,)
(M2 module2,M2 module2)
(PIP a I n4,PIP a I n4)
(PIP b O D,PIP b O D)
(PIP c O n5,PIP c O n5)
```

Instead, I'd like the output to be

```
module1, (PIP a Z A, PIP b Z B, PIP b Z B)
module2, (PIP a I n4,PIP b O D, PIP c O n5)
```

What am I doing wrong? I am quite new to Spark APIs.
Thanks

Hi @zero323

```
usgRDD.take(10).foreach(x => println(x + "%%%%%%%%%"))
```

yields...

```
%%%%%%%%%
M1 module1%%%%%%%%%
PIP a Z A%%%%%%%%%
PIP b Z B%%%%%%%%%
PIP c Y n4%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%
M2 module2%%%%%%%%%
PIP a I n4%%%%%%%%%
PIP b O D%%%%%%%%%
PIP c O n5%%%%%%%%%
```

and so on

Hi @zero323 and @Daniel Darabos
My input is very very large set of many many files (spanning in TBs). Here is sample..

```
BIN n4
BIN n5
BIN D
BIN E
PIT A I A
PIT B I B 
PIT C I C
PIT D O D
PIT E O E
DEF M1 module1
   PIP a Z A
   PIP b Z B
   PIP c Y n4
DEF M2 module2
   PIP a I n4
   PIP b O D
   PIP c O n5
```

I need all the BINS, PIT and DEF (including PIP lines below) in 3 different RDDS. Here is how I am doing this currently (from the discussion, I sense usgRDD below is wrongly computed)

```
val binRDD = levelfileRDD.filter(line => line.contains("BIN"))
val pitRDD = levelfileRDD.filter(line => line.contains("PIT"))
val usgRDD = levelfileRDD.filter(line => !line.contains("BIN") && !line.contains("PIT")).flatMap(s=>s.split("DEF").map(_.trim))
```

I need 3 types (at the moment) of RDDs because I need to perform validation later on. For example, "n4" under "DEF M2 module2" can only exist if n4 is a BIN element. From the RDDs, I hope to derive relationships using GraphX APIs (I have obviously not come upto this point). It would be ideal if each usgPairRDD (computed from usgRDD or otherwise) prints the following

```
module1, (a Z A, b Z B, c Y n4) %%%%%%%
module2, (a I n4, b O D, c O n5) %%%%%%%
```

I hope I am making sense. Apologies to the Spark Gods, if I am not.

Comment: What is the input here? It looks like you're using `textFile` to read data, right?

Comment: The input is a huge file that has been transformed into the above mentioned RDD -  usgRDD. I'd like to transform the usgRDD into  usgPairRDD (paired RDD)

Comment: Could you add an exact output form `usgRDD.take(9)`?

Comment: This is quite hard because as the data is split across multiple machines it may be that one machine has the `M` line and another has the corresponding `PIP` lines. Nevertheless, I'm sure @zero323 will have a great answer :).

Comment: If you can change the initial input read, then you can use wholeTextFiles instead, and parse the file in a non-distributed way at first.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Darabos. I now understand what you are saying. Please see the above edits to my original question on the nature of the input

Answer (score 4):

By default Spark creates a single element per line. It means that in your case every record is spread over multiple elements which, as stated by [Daniel Darabos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3318517/daniel-darabos) in the comments, can be processed by different workers.

Since it looks like your data is relatively regular and separated by an empty line you should be able to use `newAPIHadoopFile` with custom delimiter:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, Text}

val path: String = ???

val conf = new org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job().getConfiguration
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "\n\n")

val usgRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
    path, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf)
  .map{ case (_, v) => v.toString }

val usgPairRDD: RDD[(String, Seq[String])] = usgRDD.map(_.split("\n") match {
  case Array(x, xs @ _*) => (x, xs)
})
```

In Spark 2.4 or later data loading part can be also achieved using `Dataset` API:

```
val ds: Dataset[String] = spark.read.option("lineSep", "\n\n").text(path)
```