# Collect multiple lines into one array by every empty line in Spark RDD or SQL APIs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a text file in the format of `CoNLL-U` which I need to extract `Token_Label`. Example of file:

```
# newdoc id = weblog-blogspot.com_nominations_20041117172713_ENG_20041117_172713
# sent_id = weblog-blogspot.com_nominations_20041117172713_ENG_20041117_172713-0001
# text = From the AP comes this story :
1   From    from    ADP IN  _   3   case    3:case  _
2   the the DET DT  Definite=Def|PronType=Art   3   det 3:det   _
3   AP  AP  PROPN   NNP Number=Sing 4   obl 4:obl:from  _
4   comes   come    VERB    VBZ Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin   0   root    0:root  _
5   this    this    DET DT  Number=Sing|PronType=Dem    6   det 6:det   _
6   story   story   NOUN    NN  Number=Sing 4   nsubj   4:nsubj _
7   :   :   PUNCT   :   _   4   punct   4:punct _

# sent_id = weblog-juancole.com_juancole_20040324065800_ENG_20040324_065800-0005
# text = In Ramadi, there was a big demonstration.
1   In  in  ADP IN  _   2   case    2:case  _
2   Ramadi  Ramadi  PROPN   NNP Number=Sing 5   obl 5:obl:in    SpaceAfter=No
3   ,   ,   PUNCT   ,   _   5   punct   5:punct _
4   there   there   PRON    EX  _   5   expl    5:expl  _
5   was be  VERB    VBD Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Past|VerbForm=Fin   0   root    0:root  _
6   a   a   DET DT  Definite=Ind|PronType=Art   8   det 8:det   _
7   big big ADJ JJ  Degree=Pos  8   amod    8:amod  _
8   demonstration   demonstration   NOUN    NN  Number=Sing 5   nsubj   5:nsubj SpaceAfter=No
9   .   .   PUNCT   .   _   5   punct   5:punct _
```

As you can see, each sentence is being tokenized and add some labels in front of each token separated by tab `\t` (token, lemma, UD POS, etc.) and each sentence is separated by an empty line.

In order to get `Token_POS` for each sentence I use this code to result in a text for each sentence as `What_PRON if_SCON...`, then I convert this into Dataframe so I can use `withColumn` to extract tokens and tags into seprated columns as an array type for my project.

```
val testPath = "en_ewt-ud-test.conllu"
val testInput = spark.read.text(testPath).as[String]

val extractedTokensTags = testInput.map(s => s.split("\t")
.filter(x => !x.startsWith("#"))).filter(x => x.length > 0)
.map{x => if(x.length > 1){x(1) + "_" + x(3)} else{"endOfLine"}}
.map(x => x.mkString)
.reduce((s1, s2) => s1 + " " + s2).split(" endOfLine | endOfLine")

spark.sparkContext.parallelize(extractedTokensTags).toDF("arrays").show

|              arrays|
+--------------------+
|What_PRON if_SCON...|
|What_PRON if_SCON...|
|[_PUNCT via_ADP M...|
|(_PUNCT And_CCONJ...|
|This_DET BuzzMach...|
|Google_PROPN is_A...|
|Does_AUX anybody_...|
|They_PRON own_VER...|
```

This code is an absolute hack! It even looks ugly, but it did the job and gave me what I wanted until now!

**Problem:**

If the file is big, the **reduce** part will create more than one task and this results into not preserving the order of lines. (I quess I could've mess with number of shuffles or tasks, but doing one hack was enough!)

**Question:**

1. How can I group the lines based on that empty line? (I would like to get rid of that `endOfLine` hack in the `.map` and `.reduce`)
2. Is it possible to use zipWithIndex with a unique index for each line of each section so at the end I can use reduceByKey or use the same ID in my Dataframe without caring about the order?
3. Is there a better way of doing this only by Spark SQL APIs?

The desired result for the given example:

1. Array[String] so I can parallelize it into DataFrame

> Array[String] = Array(From_ADP the_DET AP_PROPN comes_VERB this_DET story_NOUN :_PUNCT)
>
> Array[String] = Array(In_ ADP Ramadi_PROPN ,_PUNCT there_PRON was_VERB a_DET big_ADJ demonstration_NOUN ._PUNCT)

Or

2. A Dataframe with 2 columns:

> Tokens: Array[String] = (From, the, AP, comes, this, story, :)
>
> Tags: Array[String] = (ADP, DET, PROPN, VERB, DET, NOUN, PUNCT)

I can handle the rest if I can have any of these two results. My main problem is not to knowing how to use the empty line as a seprator or some sort of delimiter to group the lines, and the second problem is preserving the order by ID or line by line.

Many thanks.

Update: [Parsing multiline records in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157104/parsing-multiline-records-in-scala)

I did see and try other questions about parsing a multiline text file which has `\\n` as delimiter. I already am replacing the `\\n` which something that I don't have in my dataset, so I would prefer 
1. Stay inside Spark (which as you can see it is possible)
2. Find a way to either make `reduce` not re-order or add unique id to each line so I can preserve the order

Comment: you can use only one character as a record separator in spark.. just replace "\n\n" with some character that will not come in your data ( e.g ~ ) using linux commands and feed the data to HDFS. And then use the '~' as delimiter

Comment: that is a great idea, I was hoping to not do data preparation outside of Spark. Our data scientists are using Zeppelin, so it would be nice if I could just update the CoNLL files on HDFS and they just convert them into Dataframe. (PS: I did change the \\n with something else that doesn't exist in my data, so it is possible to stay inside Spark)